# How to stop following symlinks in dropbox

Tags: dropbox, symbolic-link

What I have:

```
Dropbox\
    projects\
        serverfault\
        stackoverflow\
        superuser\
    currentProject -> projects\superuser [Sometimes I change it to other project]
```

When I sync it with other PC `currentProject` becomes real folder with files from `projects\superuser` but I need sync it as symlink.

OS is Linux on all my PC's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, this is impossible with Dropbox. The whole reason for symlinks is for them to look like and act like files.

The changes necessary are for Dropbox to make an explicity API call which the OS will tell you if it is a symlink or not.  Otherwise, all file operations pretend it is a real file.

I assume sharing the folder as a shared folder and have the Linux machine connect to it is out of the question??

Answer (score 3):

You could use dropbox "selective sync" feature, 
which allows you not to sync that folder in droppbox.
In that way, you would avoid unneeded copies but 
you can't keep your links in sync among multiple computers with dropbox so
you would have to create them on all your computers. 
Also if your links are mixed with regular files in the same folder that wouldn't work.
hope this helps.